# Restrict/deny the allowed locations for resources

Tags: azure, policy, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-group

I am looking to assign the resource policy that to limit the allowed locations where the resources can be deployed, so that I can be use only the particular resources for my work and the cost will be low.
I found [This](https://avd.aquasec.com/misconfig/azure/azure-policy/resources-allowed-locations/) but this is like manually restricted I need it in the script way.

I searched in the network but didn't find any related doc.
Can anyone help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have followed the below configuration to deny the allowed locations for resources*

Go-To ***Portal*** → and search for ***Policy***  and ***policy definition***

[image]

> I have filled the appropriate fields and i have used the below script to deny allocated locations

```
 { 
"properties": { 
"displayName": "Allowed resource types", 
"policyType": "BuiltIn",  
"mode": "Indexed",  
"description": "This policy enables you to specify the resource types that your organization can deploy. Only resource types that support 'tags' and 'location' will be affected by this policy. To restrict all resources please duplicate this policy and change the 'mode' to 'All'.", 
"metadata": { 
"version": "1.0.0",    
"category": "General"  
},   
"parameters": { 
"listOfResourceTypesAllowed": { 
"type": "Array", 
"metadata": {   
"description": "The list of resource types that can be deployed.",  
"displayName": "Allowed resource types",  
"strongType": "resourceTypes"   
}   
} 
}, 
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"not": {
"field": "type",
"in": "[parameters('listOfResourceTypesAllowed')]"
}
},
"then": {
"effect": "deny"
}
}
```

> I have assigned the policy and when I check in the assignments I am able to see

[image]

> When I check to create resource group with non allowed locations I am not able to create

[image]